# Xamarin.Forms ListView Visibility Issue

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm facing an issue with the visibility of ListView controls in Xamarin.Forms. I have a set of ListView controls, each associated with specific menu items. The idea is to show the relevant ListView when a corresponding button is clicked.

However, I'm encountering a problem where the ListView controls are not visible as expected. Instead, a box appears, and the ListView becomes visible only when this box is clicked.

Here's a simplified version of my XAML structure:

```
<!-- StackLayout containing Buttons and ListViews -->
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Buttons for different categories -->
    <Button Text="File" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <Button Text="Settings" Clicked="Button_Clicked2"/>
    <!-- ... Other buttons ... -->

    <!-- ListViews for each category -->
    <ListView x:Name="menuListView" IsVisible="False" ItemSelected="menuListView_ItemSelected">
        <!-- ListView configuration -->
    </ListView>
    <!-- ... Other ListViews ... -->
</StackLayout>
```

And in the code-behind (C#), I have separate event handlers for each button click.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Handle button click
    // ...

    // Show the relevant ListView
    menuListView.IsVisible = true;
}
```

Despite setting IsVisible to true, the ListView only becomes visible when a certain box is clicked, not immediately after the button press.

I've checked the layout structure, event handlers, and styling, but I can't seem to find the issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
My new question about items of the listview...
this is my xaml code along with the other main factors:

```
        </ListView>
        <ListView x:Name="menuListView5" ItemSelected="menuListView_ItemSelected5">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>RGBA</x:String>
                    <x:String>CMYK</x:String>
                    <x:String>Extention</x:String>
                    <x:String>Pixel Format</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
```

but it only shows `option 1` `option 2` `option 3`

Comment: If you want this to happen as soon as you click the button why not do `menuListView.IsVisible = true;` in the first line of your code?

Comment: @FreakyAli Sorry my bad i wrote `menuListView.IsVisible = true;` in the last line but in the main code it is in the first line.

Comment: @FreakyAli I also updated my quesetion (a new question). Can you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: You may need a `CollectionView` instead of `ListView` to set the `IsVisible` property.